# R : how to create multiple new values in one column and repeat line for each new value, using data in other columns?

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this :

```
data_t <- data.frame(identfiant = paste0('ID_', 1:5), 
                     date = c('2018-02-06', '2018-05-14', '2018-03-23', '2018-04-10', '2018-03-03'),
                     ndays = c(4,2,3,5,2))
```

which results in :

```
    identfiant         date  ndays
1         ID_1   2018-02-06      4
2         ID_2   2018-05-14      2
3         ID_3   2018-03-23      3
4         ID_4   2018-04-10      5
5         ID_5   2018-03-03      2
```

and i want to create a new table looking like this :

```
    identfiant          date  ndays           y
1         ID_1   2018-02-06       4  2018-02-07
2         ID_1   2018-02-06       4  2018-02-08
3         ID_1   2018-02-06       4  2018-02-09
4         ID_1   2018-02-06       4  2018-02-10
5         ID_2   2018-05-14       2  2018-05-15
6         ID_2   2018-05-14       2  2018-05-16
7         ID_3   2018-03-23       3  2018-03-24
8         ID_3   2018-03-23       3  2018-03-25
9         ID_3   2018-03-23       3  2018-03-26
10        ID_4   2018-04-10       5  2018-04-11
11        ID_4   2018-04-10       5  2018-04-12
12        ID_4   2018-04-10       5  2018-04-13
13        ID_4   2018-04-10       5  2018-04-14
14        ID_4   2018-04-10       5  2018-04-15
15        ID_5   2018-03-03       2  2018-03-04
16        ID_5   2018-03-03       2  2018-03-05
```

As we can see, each initial line is repeated `ndays` times, and the new column `y` consists of `date + 1:ndays`.

Is there any elegent way to do this with dplyr or data.table.
I absolutely do not want to use `for` loops (too long for huge data) and `seq_along`.

I thought of first creating a column that pastes all possible values together for each line, so that we would have for example    `y = '2018-02-07;2018-02-08;2018-02-09;2018-02-10'`     for the first line and then doing a `reshape(dcast)` or `separate_rows`.
My code would look like this:

```
data_t2 <- data_t %>%
 mutate(
   y = paste0(as.Date(date)+1:ndays, collapse = ";")
 ) %>%
 separate_row(y, sep = ";\\s+")
```

the problem is that to R, `data_t$date` is a vector, and since it does not treat each line separately, it tris to create a new vector `y` by treating the vector `data_t$date` at once, and wouldn't know which value of `data_t$ndays` to refer to. And we would have vector length conformity problem.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should be able to do this within `dplyr` and `tidyr`

Using `tidyr::uncount`, we can reformat the data by duplicating rows according to `ndays`.
Next, we will group the data by `identfiant` (or by both `identfiant` and `date`, depending on if `identfiant` is not unique).
Finally, we will use `mutate` to make sure our `date` field is of the right class, and then add the row number within the group (which will act like `1:ndays` for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data_t %>% 
  uncount(ndays, .remove = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(identfiant) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         y = date + row_number())
```

#### Non-`tidyr` approach:

```
df.expanded <- data_t[rep(seq(nrow(data_t)), data_t$ndays), ]

df.expanded %>% 
  group_by(identfiant) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         y = date + row_number())
```

Either way, both methods give us the following:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   identfiant [5]
   identfiant date       ndays y         
   <fct>      <date>     <dbl> <date>    
 1 ID_1       2018-02-06    4. 2018-02-07
 2 ID_1       2018-02-06    4. 2018-02-08
 3 ID_1       2018-02-06    4. 2018-02-09
 4 ID_1       2018-02-06    4. 2018-02-10
 5 ID_2       2018-05-14    2. 2018-05-15
 6 ID_2       2018-05-14    2. 2018-05-16
 7 ID_3       2018-03-23    3. 2018-03-24
 8 ID_3       2018-03-23    3. 2018-03-25
 9 ID_3       2018-03-23    3. 2018-03-26
10 ID_4       2018-04-10    5. 2018-04-11
11 ID_4       2018-04-10    5. 2018-04-12
12 ID_4       2018-04-10    5. 2018-04-13
13 ID_4       2018-04-10    5. 2018-04-14
14 ID_4       2018-04-10    5. 2018-04-15
15 ID_5       2018-03-03    2. 2018-03-04
16 ID_5       2018-03-03    2. 2018-03-05
```

Comment: thank you very much. I like your answer alot. but unfortuntely the server I work on has an older version of  `tidyr` (v0.6.0) in which the function `uncount` dos not exist ! I will keep searching so that I may find a solution to this. Thanks again.

Comment: Added an alternative for you that avoids `tidyr`.  I'm assuming you can still use `dplyr` since you have included `dplyr` syntax in your original question

Comment: Yes and thank you ver much! The second solution works !